# Remove extra spacing on List

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can't figure out how to make the swipeActions have the size of the view that is on dark, I tried placing a spacer below or text, and it just creates an ever bigger mess with some space. What would be the correct solution for this?

In case it's not clear, If you notice the purple square it's bigger than what's on it's left side, I want them both to be the same size.

[image]

```
List(someItems, id: \.self) { item in
    VStack {
        TheView()
    }
    .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: true) {     // Adds custom swipe actions
        Button {
            
        } label: {
            Label("Hide", systemImage: "eye.slash")
        }
        .tint(.accentColor)
    }
    .listRowBackground(Color(.red)) // Sets Row color or a custom color: .listRowBackground(Color("DarkBackground"))
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())    // Removes extra padding space in rows
    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)      // Removed lines between items
    .cornerRadius(10)
    .shadow(radius: 2)
    .padding(.bottom)
}
.listStyle(PlainListStyle()) // Removes extra spaces around the whole List
```

The extra space at the bottom is because of the `.padding(.bottom)`, if I remove it the size is correct, but the items would be all close together and I need some space.

Edit:

This is the view I'm using above called "TheView()", it's not much, I don't think the problem is there.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                SomeImage()
            }
            
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {

                        Text("sometext")
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            .bold()
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Text(String(xyz!))
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("$515")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .fontWeight(.light)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .padding(5)
        .padding(.horizontal, 3)
    }
    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("SomeColor")]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
}
```

Comment: What is `TheView()` guessing your problem is there.

Comment: Actually, try changing your VStack to `VStack (spacing: 0) { ...}`

Comment: @xTwisteDx that didn't work (the spacing), give me 1 min to put the subView above in the question, but it's not much.

Comment: Might try spacing -8 as well

Comment: @xTwisteDx that doesn't work

Comment: Take off the padding on your "TheView()" you've got a padding of 5 and a padding of 3 on the horizonta.

Comment: @xTwisteDx you mean this padding `.padding(.bottom)` ? Because that's the one that actually gives the space I need

Comment: No, remove the `.padding(5)` and the `.padding(.horizontal, 3)` from `TheView`

Comment: That just breaks the design of the box & doesn't fix it. That view is fine, I think the problem is in the main List view.

Comment: What you want actually? the purple view should be smaller ?

Comment: This really needs to be a [ Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I am not even sure what the exact issue is here, as the problem has not been well described.

Comment: @Yrb the problem has not been well described? I must be crazy, I said the purple buttom is bigger than it's left view and even put a picture with the red background so the difference is clear, how more clear than that you need? You want a video?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by its "left view", I am not sure in which direction it is "bigger". You attached an image that is only part of the screen. And that image does not show anything like the purple button. We don't know what the UI currently looks like or what you are trying to achieve. Everybody else as been shooting in the dark as a result. A minimal, reproducible example would allow everyone to actually see what is going on. And it won't be difficult to make.

Comment: @Yrb you can ignore this question. Everyone else understood except you which means it's well explained.